# Assembly - What is macOS's equivalence of DOS'd debug?

Tags: macos, assembly

I am new to assembly language, and I am using macOS. The book I read uses DOS's debug instruction, which could see the values in registers at any time without set breakpoints in some executable programs like lldb, and could execute basic assemble instructions like `mov ax, 2000`. I know that macOS runs on a x86_64 machine, which is different from DOS. I simply want a way that can inspect and interact with registers/memory in terminal without an formal assembly program.(For example, in DOS, type in `debug -r` and I can see all the values stored in registers).

Comment: I am not aware of any debugger with built-in assembler support. You could hack something together scripting gdb to invoke an assembler and poke the machine code into your process memory to have it executed but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: @Jester In fact, the book I read shows me that the debug in DOS HAS the assembler support.

Comment: yeah I know that .. I meant for mac :D Anyway, you can run debug inside dosbox, how about that?

Comment: Last I read, `debug.exe` doesn't even support labels, so branches have to use numeric targets.  That's pretty much total crap, so I wouldn't recommend using it.  It's one of the worst assemblers that still exists.  For anything beyond executing *one* assembly instruction to see what it does to registers, assemble + link something with gcc or NASM and start it with `starti` in GDB or LLDB and `stepi` the first instruction.  Use `layout reg` to show registers.

Answer (score 0):

In `lldb` - the stock MacOS debugger

```
register read
```

will show you all register values

Also possible with shortened syntax for quicker typing

```
re r
```

If you want the *floating point* registers (xmm* for x86-64) too included

```
re r --all
```

If you want particular register value

```
re r rax
```

`lldb` is used in current versions of `Xcode` the MacOS free programming IDE from Apple which allows you to target MacOS & iOS.

You can also go with the terminal route when you would run your program with:

```
lldb ./yourProgram
```

But this approach will require a lot of typing and knowledge about your binary, so I don't recommend it for starters.

Comment: Thanks. But I haven't found a way to use lldb without run a program. I want to view the values in registers at any time(not only when it runs til a breakpoint was found in a certain program, which DOS's debug could.)

Comment: I do believe you're asking for impossible, technically any debugger must run the program to be able to evaluate the current state of registers of the CPU. DOS `Debug` might gave you the illusion it wasn't running your program, but somehow it needs to execute the program instructions. A quick glance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_(command) confirms this.

Comment: @Evian what is your intent? The content of the registers is meaningless until you enter your program. So at the very least, you could set a breakpoint at the very start of your program and examine the registers there.

Comment: I think @Evian would like to operate in interactive mode, as is possible with DEBUG in DOS.